# PHP, скачать cраницу сайта (curl и file_get_contents не помогает.)

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

Через браузер сохраняется нормально, через PHP созранить не могу.
Что я пробовал.

```html
@header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$ch = curl_init('https://dtps-ibe.o-rsb.de/hotel?taid=PTS22790&adult=2&stars=4&rgid=10036&rid=342&sea=1&cyid=&dur=8&ddate=2022-05-29&rdate=2022-06-07&dur=8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refer);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Еще такой вариант, тоже не работает.

```html
$page = file_get_contents('https://dtps-ibe.o-rsb.de/hotel?taid=PTS22790&adult=2&stars=4&rgid=10036&rid=342&sea=1&cyid=&dur=8&ddate=2022-05-29&rdate=2022-06-07&dur=8');
echo $page; //Вывод содержимого
```

Comment: В чём выражается ваше "не работает"?

Comment: На сколько я вижу, то пишет "Уважаемый пользователь, Чтобы иметь возможность использовать все функции этого сайта, пожалуйста, активируйте Javascript."

Comment: Вы не скачаете такой сайт через `curl` или `file_get_contents`. Используйте selenium или что-то аналогичное

Comment: вы что-то конкретное хотите с этой странице получить? или просто сохранить страницу? Если вы в бразурее откроете "исходный код", то увидите то же самое, что и сами скачиваете. Контент загружается асинхронно. Если нужны именно какие-то данные,  то отройте панель разработчика вкладку сеть, ткните в xhr запросы, обновите страницу и смотрите что и откуда загружается. Потом скопируйте URL этого источника, и копируйте данные из него.